# You attempted to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, winforms, 32bit-64bit

i have 3 projects, in Visual Studio 2013, using winforms, in the same solution, the first project is the StartUp Project, project two is a signature pad and project three is a fingerprint reader, this last, run to 32 bits becuse sdk is build in 32 bits and i load this dll with DLLImport, the properties of startup project in build are (run Any CPU) and project of pad signature, are same as startup project.

if i run my aplication, the pad signature executed correctly but fingerprint reader throw exception: You attempted to load a program with an incorrect format

i changes properties for startup project set run 32 bits and F5, the fingerprint reader execute correctly but the same exceptions show in pad signature, tried to diferents combinations, but one of the two always raise the error, how can i solve this problem? any idea? i hope it being understood me, thanks everybody for your time, cheers!!!

Comment: Is it possible there's a third-party reliance, a reference DLL, that is being loaded, and it is _that assembly_ that is causing the error?

Comment: ok, the Dll works fine, if in the project i set run for 32 bits, but if unchecked  32 bits in properties of project, this raiser the exception , i set chcked 32 bits and run perfect, the problem is when other project dont runt in 32 bits

Comment: *All* of your projects have to target the same bitness. If one is 32-bit, they *all* need to be 32-bit. If one is 64-bit, they *all* need to be 64-bit. No way around it, this is a hard limitation of the system.